# How to test the type of a Cloud Firestore field, in Security Rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there a way to test for the type of inputs, in Security Rules?

The best I can come up with is:

```
  if request.resource.data.lastOpened.toMillis() > 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `is` operator.  For example:

```
value is bool

value is string

value is timestamp
```

You can see a complete list of types here: https://youtu.be/qbd_4LT0Y4s